# Export enums from an interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have interface with enum values:
mydriver.ts:

```
export const enum MyDriverStatus {
    DRIVER_DISABLED,
    DRIVER_AWAKE,
    DRIVER_SLEEP
}

export const enum MyDriverResult {
    DRIVER_NONE,
    DRIVER_NOK,
    DRIVER_OK
}

export default interface MyDriver {
    enable: boolean;
    status: MyDriverStatus;
    result: MyDriverResult ;
    value: number;
    time: number;
}
```

On the component side, I imported the interface:

```
import { MyDriver, MyDriverStatus, MyDriverResult } from '../interfaces/mydriver';
```

When I tried to initialize my variable, An error appeared:

```
export class Tab5Page implements OnInit {


  drv: MyDriver= {
    result: DRIVER_NONE,
    status: DRIVER_DISABLED,
    value: 0,
    time: 0,
    enable: false
  };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

> Cannot find name DRIVER_NONE.
>   Cannot find name DRIVER_DISABLED.

Comment: How are you initializing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to qualify the `enum` usages. They're not implicit.

```
result: MyDriverResult.DRIVER_NONE,
status: MyDriverStatus.DRIVER_DISABLED,
```